# Controlling the iRobot Create 2 with MATLAB

Tags: irobot-create

I teach a university sophomore level MATLAB programming class for engineers, and I am planning on using the create2 for their final project. There is a nice simulator and MATLAB toolbox for the Create, but the toolbox utilizes some of the commands that no longer exist on the Create 2, thus it doesn't work correctly. And of course is doesn't support any of the newer commands. In addition, I want to be able to "cut the cord" so I am using a Raspberry Pi on the Create to pipe data to the serial port, and TCPIP sockets to send the data from a remote computer running MATLAB to the Pi/Create. If anyone is working on a similar configuration, I'd love to trade notes and share the pain.

Answer (score 2):

The API hasn't changed *that* much.  An overview of the changes can be found on the last page of the [OI Spec](http://www.irobot.com/~/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/create_2_Open_Interface_Spec.pdf).  I am confused as to what might be causing the toolbox to break.  Can you elaborate?

Using a RasPI to pipe serial data over TCP/IP to a desktop sounds like an expensive and error-prone way to "cut the cord".  Using a serial to bluetooth or XBee module will be much easier.

Comment: Just as a note, there is a Bluetooth-to-Create 2 project that can be found here: http://www.irobot.com/~/media/MainSite/PDFs/About/STEM/Create/Bluetooth_Serial.pdf?la=en The robot will show up as a serial port (once you pair with its module).

Comment: The logic for the choice of the WIFI/Pi is mainly to give us more flexibility. In addition to a 'dumb' network to serial converter, we can also:

* control the robot via an onboard program on the pi
* incorporate a camera
* access from any network device
* avoid bluetooth pairing issues

The cost for a bluetooth adapter and cable is approx $30. The cost for a pi with wifi and cable is around $45.

Comment: You are right that the API hasn't changed that much, but the the MATLAB toolbox relied on the "wait" commands that were removed. So now we have to change that so that the wait logic is on the controller side, which means more two-way communication. It also used the scripting commands which were removed. Again, there are workarounds, but it certainly doesn't work 'as is'

Comment: sorry about the formatting of the first comment. The editing capability times out after 5 minutes or I would have fixed it...